# Photoshop 19 brush color is always black

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, brush

I'm new to photoshop and very confused about pretty much everything...

So for some reason I cant change brush color now

Here's video example:

https://streamable.com/2le1f

Image mode is rgb 8 bit, ctrl key not stuck :) Looks like it changing secondary color, and drawing using main color (black)

Comment: Is your CMD or CTRL key held down or stuck while you are selecting you colour?

Comment: Try selecting the foreground colour.  You're only changing the background colour.

Comment: @BillyKerr how do I do that?

Comment: Click on the foreground colour square (the black one shown at the bottom of the tool box).

Comment: @BillyKerr looks like this was the problem, I clicked on that 'background color' square and didnt noticed it. Can you answer and I mark it as correct answer?

Comment: @csharpnewbie - I'm not sure if there's enough there to turn it into a full answer. The admins here don't like one-liners.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like **your Option/Alt key is stuck or otherwise depressed.**

Your cursor indicates Option/Alt is depressed:

[image]

The fact that the *background* color *is* changing is also an indicator of the Option/Alt key being depressed.

That being posted.. you can pick a background color (by depressing Option/Alt when choosing a color) than tap the x key to swap the foreground/background color... and paint.

Comment: Can you please re-watch video, at the very end when I alt-tabbing to OBS (recording app), I pressed alt-tab to do that, and you can see in the photoshop window on the MenuStrip component (with File Edit Image Layer etc) that hotkey letters gets underlined, meaning that I pressed Alt key. And before that they haven't had underlines, meaning Alt wasn't pressed? Maybe I hit some unknown hotkey and everything is weirdly reversed now? Kinda annoying to hit x every single time

Comment: Everything in your video eludes to the Alt key being depressed, not merely the end of the video.  Have you even bothered to just reboot the machine?

Comment: yes, I rebooted and problem persisted. however, question answered in comments to my question - solution is to  'Click on the foreground colour square (the black one shown at the bottom of the tool box)'